# How to do a correlated subquery in slick?

Tags: scala, slick

I need to do the following query

select fieldA from tableA where not exists (select id from tableB where fieldK = tableA.fieldA)

How can I do this in slick? Using slick 2.10

Comment: Also, as a new user don't get discouraged for the down-votes ? At least whoever down-voted, i hope, would had the minimum courtesy to tell what they think is wrong about the question. My best guess is that, may be the question lacked some effort from the op part. Any way good luck.

Comment: Thanks for being nice. I did try to solve the issue before posting it. I guess I'll have to try harder next time. Fair enough.

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
for {
  a <- A if !B.filter(b => b.fieldK === a.fieldA).exists
} yield (a.fieldA)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Biswanath

```
implicit session =>
  val B = for { r <- TableB } yield r.fieldK
  val q = for { r1 <- TableA if !B.filter(b => b.a = r1.fieldA).exists } yield (r1.fieldA) 
  val materializedResult = q.buildColl[List]
```

Above, the ".a" was a method in the query to represent the single field returned. This gave me a List[String] and in the mysql query.log I got exactly the query I wanted.